# Play! Framework: Best practice to use URLs in separate JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, external, playframework

I am currently reorganizing a Play! project where there is a lot of JS
code in the HTML template files. This code should be moved to external
JS files for better readability and faster page loading times. However,
when I just create a JS file in the public folder, all the
@{Controller.method} link replacements are no longer working. I was
thinking about calling some initialization function from the HTML
templates which just supplies the required URLs like

```
initialize({ "Application.doThis" : "@{Application.doThis}"})
```

however this is becoming very cumbersome and error-prone with any URL
that is added. Another thing is, that the I18N also no longer works. So
what is the best practice for scenarios like these, where you have your
JS code in a separate file but still want to use URL generation and
I18N in your JS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the main template, generate a 'Javascript router', something like:

```
<script>
    var routes = {
        doThis: #{jsAction @Application.doThis(user, ':param1', ':param2') /},
        doThat: #{jsAction @doThat() /}
    } 
</script>
```

And then in any 'static' javascript file, use this router:

```
$.get(routes.doThis({param1: x, param2: 'yop'}))
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what I had in mind, however that actually means I have to a lot of boilerplate code which I have to extend whenever a new route comes up, which is easily forgotten. Another thing is using i18n for messages inside JavaScript, one could of course write such a "router" for messages as well but this effectively duplicates all I18N keys in JavaScript.

Comment: You can already use the #{18n /} tag. I guess we could provide a tag that expose the whole route file via javascript, but it could lead to security concerns.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to get the framework to parse your javascript, or your CSS, or anything else in the static directories. Here's an easy solution.

Add a `controllers.StaticParser` controller:

```
package controllers;
import play.mvc.Controller;

public class StaticParser extends Controller {
    public static void parse(String route) {
        render("/" + route);
    }
}
```

To your `conf/routes` file add:

```
GET  /parse/{<.*>route} StaticParser.parse
```

The regexp in that route is very important, otherwise you can't add pathing to the request.
To request a parsed static resource, such as a js script, use:

```
<script src="/parse/public/javascripts/test.js"
   language="javascript" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the `#{script 'test.js' /}` format, because the script tag looks for the static file. To correct that irksome-ness, here's a shameless hack of the script tag: the `#{parsescript 'test.js'/}` tag. It should go to `/views/tags/parsescript.tag`:

```
{
 *  insert a parsescript tag in the template.
 *  by convention, referred script must be put under /public/javascripts
 *    src     (required)   : script filename, without the leading path "/public/javascripts"
 *    id      (opt.)       : sets script id attribute
 *    charset (opt.)       : sets source encoding - defaults to current response encoding
 *
 *    #{parsescript id:'datepicker' , src:'ui/ui.datepicker.js', charset:'${_response_encoding}' /}
}*
%{
    (_arg ) && (_src = _arg);

    if (!_src) {
        throw new play.exceptions.TagInternalException("src attribute cannot be empty for script tag");
    }
    _src = "/public/javascripts/" + _src
    try {
        _abs = play.mvc.Router.reverseWithCheck(_src, play.Play.getVirtualFile(_src), false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new play.exceptions.TagInternalException("File not found: " + _src);
    }
}%
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"#{if _id} id="${_id}"#{/if}#{if _charset} charset="${_charset}"#{/if}  src="/parse${_abs}"></script>
```

It works exactly like the `#{script /}` tag, but parses the file before returning it: `#{parsescript 'test.js' /}`

One could equally shamelessly hack the `#{stylesheet /}` tag, but I think I've taken up enough space already.

---