# AJAX Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework, playframework-1.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play! Framework: Best practice to use URLs in separate JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209420/play-framework-best-practice-to-use-urls-in-separate-javascript-files)

we are able  to insert successfully values in database with this code:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "@{Receipes.add('nameIng','quantity')}",
```

but not with the parameters like:

$.ajax({type:

```
"POST", url: "@{Receipes.add(':nameIng',':quantity')}",
                    data: {nameIng: "Potato", quantity: "2" } });
```

any clues?

Comment: What happens? What's the generated source?

Comment: when I pass static values directly in add function it works, but when we pass with data: {nameIng: "Potato", quantity: "2" } it doesnt save anything

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [jsAction](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/tags#jsaction) template tag. In your case, it could be used like this:

```
var addReceipeAction = #{jsAction @Receipes.add(':nameIng', ':quantity') /};
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: addReceipeAction({nameIng: "Potato", quantity: 2})});
```

Comment: ok, and how you will use the addReceipeAction?

Comment: Please read my answer again. The second line of the code has an example AJAX call. You just invoke `addReceipeAction({nameIng: "Potato", quantity: 2})` and it returns the correct URL.